# Backbone.View.model.on('change:...') trigged only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, model-view-controller

I'm doing ajax file upload for post via modal window with preview in post. Every post has it's own model and a view. Modal window is also a separate view, binded to existing DOM element.

When `Attach` button in post view is clicked, I call .open() from modal view, passing post model to modal view as settings:

```
POST VIEW:
======================
ModalAttach.open({
  postModel : this.model
});
```

When file in modal view is uploaded, I add server response to passed Post model to render it later in post itself as a preview:

```
MODAL VIEW:
======================
// file upload success
success: function(data) {
  // if it's first call, set []
  var imagesUploaded = self.postModel.get('images_uploaded') || [];
  // add server response to array
  imagesUploaded.push(data);
  // rewrite current model array to new array
  self.postModel.set({ 'images_uploaded' : imagesUploaded });
}
```

To render preview in post (before real submitting), I've got a function

```
POST VIEW:
======================
renderUploadedImages: function () {
  var self = this;
  this.$uploadedImagesWrapper = this.$('.b-uploaded__images');

  if (this.model.get('images_uploaded')) {
    this.$uploadedImagesWrapper.empty();
    this.model.get('images_uploaded').forEach(function (uploadedImage) {
      self.$uploadedImagesWrapper.append(
        uploadedImageTemplate({
          'source': uploadedImage.source
        })
      )
    });
  }
}
```

And to trigger image render, I bind a listner to track when model.images_uploaded is changed by modal view:

```
POST VIEW:
======================
initialize: function () {
  this.addEvents();
  this.renderUploadedImages();
},

addEvents: function () {
  var self = this;

  this.model.on('change:images_uploaded', function () {
    self.renderUploadedImages();
  })
},
```

The problem is `renderUploadedImages()` in Post view is trigged only once, at first upload. Other changes are not caught (when postModel.get('images_uploaded').length becomes 2,3,etc..). What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is due to the fact that the pointer hasn't changed. Is it possible to use a Collection here? You could then leverage the `add` event.

Answer (score 0):

When you do like this :

```
var imagesUploaded = self.postModel.get('images_uploaded') || [];
// add server response to array
imagesUploaded.push(data);
// rewrite current model array to new array
self.postModel.set({ 'images_uploaded' : imagesUploaded });
```

The first time, if you check `self.postModel.get('images_uploaded')` you will find it `undefined`, that's why when you set it the event `change:images_uploaded` is triggered.

But the second time you call the `success` method you don't change the the model attribute, it's always pointing to the same object (array), you just change the array value.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/XjrE8/1/)